# Get connecting IP from specified ports that using by other program

Tags: c#, networking, ip, ports

Does anyone know how to **Get connecting IP from a specified port that is using by another program.** in C#.

Thanks

Comment: I tried to listen a port and get the connected IP, but it only works if the port is free. Otherwise conflict occurs

Answer (score 2):

So you basically want to build your own version of `netstat` in C#?

[Build your own netstat.exe with c#](https://timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstat.exe-with-c/)