# Listen to a port that is in use

Tags: c#, networking, port, ip, listener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get connecting IP from specified ports that using by other program.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738155/get-connecting-ip-from-specified-ports-that-using-by-other-program)

If a port is used by a program, is there any way I can listen that port and get the connected IP on that port?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738155

Comment: The 'listen' part makes it not exactly duplicate. But the answers will be more or less the same. Voting to Close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you cannot listen on a port that another process is already listening on.
2. But yes, you can determine the TCP/IP connections currently active on that port, as has been answered in your [exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738155/get-connecting-ip-from-specified-ports-that-using-by-other-program) question (namely using `netstat`).

If this doesn't answer your question, you should try to give more information what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, there is a game server application runs on my server, it opens ports for communication with clients. I want to write a program(or other ways) to monitor these ports, get the IP addresses of the connected clients, then record them.
Thank you

Comment: And the answer is -- *drumroll* --: `netstat`

Comment: Or a packet sniffer, as @bua pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You can also sniff whole network interface, and filter your related ports of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly you'd do it in code, but the information is available by running `netstat -b`.